# App expands to full screen in Confluence

Tags: rally, confluence

I'm trying to add a Rally app to Confluence via the SDK.  I'm successful, however, the app expands to fill the whole page covering Confluence headers.  How do I restrict the app from expanding full screen?  I've added a class that limits the height and width of app, but it still expands to full screen covering the Confluence header.

Here's my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Hierarchical Grid Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/sdk.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.override('Rally.sdk.Bootstrapper', {
        _launchAppInViewport: function (className, settings, timeboxScope) {
            this._wireIoHeaderHandlers();
            this.app = this._createApp(className, settings, timeboxScope);
            this.app.render('rallyDiv');
        }
    });
        Rally.onReady(function() {
        Ext.define('Rally.example.HierarchicalGrid', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',
                items: [
                { xtype: 'container', itemId: 'rallyDiv'}
                ],
                autoCreateViewPort:false,
                launch: function() {
                    Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
                        context: {project: '/project/9400054800'},
                        models: ['userstory'],
                        autoLoad: true,
                        enableHierarchy: true
                    }).then({
                        success: this._onStoreBuilt,
                        scope: this
                    });
                },            
                _onStoreBuilt: function(store) {
                    this.down('#rallyDiv').add({
                        xtype: 'rallytreegrid',
                        context: this.getContext(),
                        store: store,
                        columnCfgs: [
                            'Name',
                            'ScheduleState',
                            'Owner'
                        ]
                    });
                }
            });

            Rally.launchApp('Rally.example.HierarchicalGrid', {
              name: 'Hierarchical Grid Example',
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="rallyDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apps are designed to fill an entire window and use a Viewport object to do so- this is why it's filling the screen.  Is it possible instead in confluence to just create an iframe of the appropriate size and link to your App-external.html served elsewhere?

Otherwise you should be able to add a small override at the top of your App.js to change the behavior of Rally.launchApp to do what you want:

```
Ext.override('Rally.sdk.Bootstrapper', {
    _launchAppInViewport: function (className, settings, timeboxScope) {
        this._wireIoHeaderHandlers();
        this.app = this._createApp(className, settings, timeboxScope);

        //this is the code that launches the app in the viewport
        //Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
        //    layout: 'fit',
        //    items: [ this.app ]
        //});

        //instead, just render it to your target div
        this.app.render('myElement');
    }
});
```

This isn't ideal but should work for you.  I'll submit a feature request to better support rendering apps in non-fullscreen environments.

Comment: Yes, I could use an iframe, but I was hoping to either disable the viewport with something like autoCreateViewPort:false or render it to a div with a renderto, but I can't seem to get either to work.  Suggestions?  Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: Kyle could you be a bit more explicit how I add the override?  I'm assuming it goes to the top of the App.js.  What do I need to change in your code to get it to work with my code?  I know the div ID needs to change for sure.  Do I uncomment out the Ext.create('Ext.Viewport' code and incorporate my code there?  Thanks!

Comment: yep, just add that override block above the Ext.override line I included above.  You can delete the commented out Ext.Viewport code.  Then just change 'myElement' to be the id of the div you want the app rendered to.

Comment: I modified the code above to include your override, but it still isn't rendering to the DIV tag.  Is it working for you?